# Zend2 Calling A View In A Form Action Script

Tags: php, zend-framework2, dompdf

I need to POST to a custom view in ZendFramework2.

In my Module folder I added a new module called `zfc-user`

I override the template files by creating a new route

```
   'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'zfc-user' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
```

That works.

Then I added a custom view at application/pdf/ called index.phtml

But when I do `<?php echo $this->url('pdf'); ?>`

```
Message:
Route with name "pdf" not found

'pdf' => array(
                 'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/pdf',
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Pdf',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
 use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;

 class PdfController extends AbstractActionController {

     public function indexAction() {
    // Instantiate new PDF Model
         $pdf = new PdfModel();
         // set filename
         $pdf->setOption('filename', 'invoice.pdf');
         // Defaults to "8x11"
         $pdf->setOption('paperSize', 'a4');
         // paper orientation
         $pdf->setOption('paperOrientation', 'portrait');

         return $pdf;
     }
 }
```

Rout

```
'pdf' => array(
                 'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/pdf',
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Pdf',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),


'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
             'Application\Controller\Pdf' => 'Application\Controller\PdfController'
         ),
     ),


My form is at Application/view/zfc-user/user/index.phtml
Action script is Application/view/application/pdf/index.phtml
```

Form

```
<form action="pdf/index.phtml" method="POST" id="printInvoice" name="printInvoice" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="yourName" id="yourName" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you write the route `pdf` in `module\Common\config\module.config.php`? Do you have the controller in `module\Application\Controller\` ?

Comment: Ok if you see the code the way I have it now,  its view/application/pdf/index.phtml is all set. But how can i post to that page from view/zfc-user/user/index.phtml

Comment: As it is MVC, you cannot post to a phtml file directly. You have to use an action to perform this.

Comment: I had this working yesterday but everything was in the vendor files. So I moved it all to try and work with the MVC better and not I cant post to it. Do you understand what I am trying to do? I am posting the content of a form to a html page which is then rendered to a pdf. What can I do at this point to make this work?